# Zend Framework 2 Module config from database

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

i am currently working on a project with zend 2 framework and i am trying to find out if its possible to controll whether a module is activ or not by the database.

I am trying to create an admin panel for my project and there i want to active and deactivate modules.

One thought was to load the config from the database in the 
"index.php" file before this line of code :

```
// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/basic.config.php')->run();
```

So instead of using the config from basic.config.php i will load the data from the database and create an array just like the one in the basic.config.php file.

Would this be the right way to achieve this ?

Is it also possible to load a module config from database ? So i can change the route for a module from the admin panel.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to write information from admin panel in configuration files by [Writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.config.writer.html). If you use [PhpArray](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.config.writer.html#zend-config-writer-phparray) then read configuration without parsing and reading from files is faster than the database.

Comment: Looks great, i will try this one out !